# Symmetric matrices with additional conditions?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, symmetry, block-matrices

I have a $m\times m$ symmetric matrix $\{x_{ij}\}_{i,j\in I}$. We now partition the index set $I = \{1,...,m\}$. Let $S$ be the set of partitions of the index set . We denote any partition in $S$ by $[k]$, where $k$ is some element in $[k]$. Clearly for any $S$, $\bigcup_{{[k]}\in S} [k] = I$. Now, I have the following conditions, for all $[k]$ :

$$\forall p,q \in I: \{x_{pi}: i\in [k] \} = \{x_{qi'}: i'\in [k] \}$$

Now, it is easy to infer that if all the $[k]$ are singletons then all the $x_{ij}$ are the same number. On the other hand if $[k] = I$ then all the rows are the same set of elements, but are a permutation of one another. I am confused about what happens in between ? i.e. there are many $[k]$ larger than a singleton. Can I derive a simple condition which encompasses all $x_{ij}$? Are such matrices known ?

---

I think the resultant condition is that the matrix $\{x_{ij}\}$ is a block matrix, with each block being the same symmetric matrix. I am not sure how to prove it yet though !

Comment: What's $x_{pi}$ and $x_{qi'}$? What does your main condition mean?

Also I find the notation $\cup_k [k]$ incorrect. Shouldn't it be $\cup_{k \in [k]} k$ or simply $\cup_{[k]} k$?

Comment: @DanielP you were right, Is the question clearer now ? Also, I guess the conditions are going to look like $\{x_{ij}\}$ being a block matrix with very strict conditions on blocks.

Comment: How does $k$ connect to $[k]$? In $\cup_{k \in I} [k]$, we should be able to figure out what $[k]$ is from $k$, but if $k$ is just an element of $[k]$, then $[k]$ is ambigous. For example if $k=3, m=5$, $[k]$ could be any subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that contains $3$. I'm probably misunderstanding something, so can you clear up what $\cup_{k \in I} [k]$ means?

Comment: And I still don't see what the condition says. You renamed $p$ to $q$, and $i$ to $i'$, of course those sets are going to be equal, because they are literally the same thing.

Comment: So basically, I want to talk about partitionings of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. For example, $\{1,2,3\}$,$\{4,5\}$ is one possible partitioning. I call each partition by a randomly picked element from the partition itself. For example, here it would be $[2]$ and $[4]$. But you may also call then $[3]$ and $[5]$.

Comment: @DanielP You have been right all along, I have changed the conditions to what i meant. So what I want to say is that for any two rows  denoted by $p$ and $q$, the elements in the columns indexed by $[k]$, form the same set. Better now ? Also, thanks for bearing with me and not downvoting :D

Comment: Okay, it's getting clearer, but I'd like to suggest something. Let's call the set of partitions something else, for example, $S$. Because right now, $[k]$ is sometimes used for $[k] = \{1,2,3\}$ and $[k] = \{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$. That way we can simply say $S \subseteq P(I)$, and $[k] \in S$. Then rewrite the union notation to $\cup_{[k] \in S} [k] = I$ (the current one is technically still incorrect, because there might not exist a $[k]$ for all $k$'s). (Edit: $P(I)$ is the powerset of $I$; the set of all its subsets.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134371/discussion-between-sagarm-and-daniel-p).

Answer (score 1):

I found a symmetical matrix that works for $m = 5$, $S = \{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$.

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&1&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, each row in the first $3$ columns always contain all the numbers in $\{0,1\}$, and each row in the last $2$ columns also always contain $\{0,1\}$.

I feel like this has to be possible for any $m$ and $S$, but I couldn't find a way to fill the matrix with the values $\{0,1,2\}$. So you just have to be careful to keep the symmetry, and you might not be able to use $\max_{[k] \in S} |[k]|$ numbers (which is $3$ in this case).